# Convergence/divergence of alternating series if leibnitz-criterias don't hold

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a question to the following alternating serie:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}*\frac{n}{n+3}$

I wanna check if the serie converges so I apply the three Leibnitz-Criterias:

1) $x_k*x_{k+1} \leq 0 $

2) $ | x_{k+1}| \leq | x_k|$

3) $lim_{k=0}^{\infty} x_{k} = 0$

I find that 1) holds but 2) and 3) do not hold and thus, convergence can't be guaranteed anymore. Can I assume that the serie diverges or do I have to apply other tools. Or to ask more generally: how do I have to proceed if one of the three Leibnitz-Criterias does not hold?

thanks a lot

Comment: The terms do not have limit $0$: automatic divergence.  Failure of 3) always ensures divergence. Failure of 2) does not.

Comment: Thanks André! So if 2) doesnt hold we go for the ratio-test?

Comment: You are welcome. There is no "universal" tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you may just notice that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|(-1)^n \frac{n}{n+3}\right|=1 \neq 0
$$ implying that this series is **divergent**.

Comment: We learned that we can't make a statement about convergence/divergence if the limes to infinity is = 1. Only if it's < 1 oder > 1? Or do I mix something up with the ratio-test?

Comment: @Fill You may recall that any convergent series must have its general term tending to $0$.

Comment: Yeah sure, I was being dumb. Thanks a lot!